# Get buttons to copy theme styles in plug-in

Tags: wordpress, plugins

So I’ve started building plug-ins to help develop my skills and I’ve built something that pulls in custom fields from posts and displays them.

Each row has a button. However I’m finding that the buttons aren’t taking on the styling from the theme. I’m using Elementor, BUT I don’t want to code in the classes for Elementor because I’d like the code to work across most themes.

What’s the best way of going about this, or is it even possible? Do I need to run some fancy code or just allow the user to edit the button styles themselves? Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you are looking for? Is this plugin an Elementor Extension or a normal plugin? I know you mentioned Elementor. Are you talking about in the page builder?

Answer (score 0):

If you want others to use your plugin you should at least add default styles. Most websites have hideously inconsistent code nowadays (Elementor is one of the reasons why btw), so you can't rely on that to properly style your components.

That being said; buttons in Elementor are usually styled links, like the one below. I expect that's your problem.

```
<a href="#" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm" role="button">
    <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
        <span class="elementor-button-icon elementor-align-icon-right">
            <svg [modified]></svg>          
    </span>
        <span class="elementor-button-text">#</span>
    </span>
</a>
```